# Seats Academy calculation in SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My allocation algorithm need to be based on remaining seats of each academy quota of seat.

Here is an illustration of my tables:

tblAcademy

```
    Acad_id name  numberOfSeats
   ------------------------------
    1       A        2
    2       B        2
    3       C        1
    4       D        5
    5       E        3
```

tblStudent

```
    stud_Id name   `stud_purcentage` `stud_result`   acad_id
   ----------------------------------------------------------
     1       Alex     100               `Pass`         
     2       Lee      80.5              `Pass`         
     3       Lea      40.3              `Fail`         
     4       Loane    10                `Fail`
     5       john     50                `Pass`
```

tblAcademy_selection

```
   stud_id Acad_id order_preference
   --------------------------------
    1      1          1
    1      3          2
    4      3          1
    4      2          2
    4      4          3
```

My algorithm:

```
SqlConnection dbcon = new SqlConnection(_conString);
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
        scmd.CommandText = "SELECT stud_Id,stud_fname,stud_purcentage,stud_totalMarks FROM tblStudent where stud_result='Pass' order by stud_purcentage Desc";
        scmd.Connection = dbcon;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dbcon.Open();

        da.Fill(dt);
        string[] array = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        // foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
        
            array[a] = dt.Rows[a]["stud_Id"].ToString();
            SqlCommand scmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            scmd2.CommandText = "select acad_Id,stud_Id from(SELECT tas.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stud_id ORDER BY order_preference) AS row_id FROM tblAcademy ta JOIN tblAcademy_Selection tas ON ta.acad_Id = tas.acad_Id WHERE ta.numberOfSeats > 0 and stud_Id IN('" + array[a] + "')) DTL WHERE row_id = 1";
            scmd2.Connection= dbcon;
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            string[] array2 = new string[dt2.Rows.Count];
            string[] array3 = new string[dt2.Rows.Count];
            for (int a2 = 0; a2 < dt2.Rows.Count; a2++)
            {
               String acad_Id = dt2.Rows[a2]["acad_Id"].ToString();
                array2[a2] = dt2.Rows[a2]["stud_id"].ToString();
                //string[,] array3 = new string[array2[a2],];
                SqlCommand scmd3 = new SqlCommand();
                scmd3.CommandText = "update tblStudent set acad_id='" + acad_Id + "' where stud_Id='" + array2[a2] + "'";
                scmd3.Connection = dbcon;
                scmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //ListBox1.Items.Add(array5);

            }
          
        }
        getStudent();
```

On the `scmd2` my sql is looking for a static column numberOfSeats `WHERE ta.numberOfSeats > 0` (the academy quota) and it is not what I am searching for.

What I need is the `where` condition be base on the calculation of the total number of row for each acadID in tblStudent - the numberOfSeat (academy quota) of each acadID in tblAcademy.

Here is the code to get the remaining seat sql code:

```
SELECT distinct ta.acad_Id, numberOfSeats - Count(ts.acad_id) OVER (
    PARTITION BY ta.acad_Id
) as remainingSeat
FROM tblAcademy ta,
     tblStudent ts
where ta.acad_Id = ts.acad_Id or ts.acad_Id is null
```

I am having difficulty to target the sql code the `smcd2 command text` to the `remainingSeat` alias instead of `ta.numberOfSeats`

Comment: Expected results would help. And the SQL code in the C# block contains columns that are not present in your table definitions at the top

Comment: I have added more info of my algorithm and table

Comment: Please describe the logic you are trying to achieve, it's very unclear. It seems you are trying to allocate `Student` to `Academy` based on `order_preference` but it's not clear how you want to do that, eg what happens if there are too many students for one academy? It's likely the whole algorithm can be done in SQL in one batch

Comment: A student can select many academy and this selection is recorded in the tblAcademy_selection but only one academy has to be allocated per student. When the allocation is launched the system will have to select those who pass and allocate those who have the best percentage first. Depending on the selection the student make in the tblAcademy_selection if the first choice academy is full then the second choice is taken in consideration and so on,if all academy that he/she selected is seat is full then no academy will be allocated to him/she.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overthinking this. To find the number of remaining seats, you just need a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT
  ta.acad_Id,
  ta.numberOfSeats - ts.cn as remainingSeat
FROM tblAcademy ta
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cn
    FROM tblStudent ts
    WHERE ta.acad_Id = ts.acad_Id
) ts
WHERE ta.numberOfSeats - ts.total > 0;

-- or as a pre-grouped joined 

SELECT
  ta.acad_Id,
  ta.numberOfSeats - ts.cn as remainingSeat
FROM tblAcademy ta
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      ts.acad_Id,
      COUNT(*) AS cn
    FROM tblStudent ts
) ts ON ta.acad_Id = ts.acad_Id
WHERE ta.numberOfSeats - ts.cn;
```

It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do with the query in `scmd2`

Side notes:

- **Always** parameterize your queries, do *not* inject data into them.
- Don't use old-style `,` cross-joins, they were deprecated 30 years ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The sql is working. The problem that I am facing is to point the WHERE ta.numberOfSeats > 0 in my smcd2 command text to the alias remainingSeat that you have send me. My goal is to look that if the remaining seats is 0 the acadID in tblAcademy will no longer accept student and loop to the student second choice found in the tblAcademy_Selection. I need that each time an acadID is added in tblStudent the acadID in question will be decrement on the numberOf Seats in the tblAcademy,this is why I want it to point to the remainingSeats alias that you have done.

Comment: OK so you can place it in an `APPLY` then refer to it in the `WHERE`, have edited

Comment: How should i write it please? I am confused about the APPLY

Comment: ah sorry i have just saw that, but how to merge this sql statement with one that i have done in scmd2, as this sql is just calculating the seat remaining and make making a comparison if either it is greater than 0. In scmd2 it is also checking the academy selection of the each student by the order of preference and those who passed and have best percentage order by best to worst which is stored in array[a],it was done in the scmd connection.

Comment: ` select acad_Id,stud_Id from
(SELECT ta.acad_Id,
  ta.numberOfSeats - ts.cn as remainingSeat,tas.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stud_id ORDER BY order_preference) 
AS row_id FROM tblAcademy ta OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cn
    FROM tblStudent ts
    WHERE ta.acad_Id = ts.acad_Id
)
ts JOIN tblAcademy_Selection tas ON ta.acad_Id = tas.acad_Id
WHERE ta.numberOfSeats - ts.cn > 0) dtl WHERE row_id = 1 ` .                                         I have try this but I am getting: 'The column 'acad_Id' was specified multiple times for 'dtl'. ' I am totally stuck.